# Why can't I find my app.config file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, configuration

I was under the impression Visual Studio 2008 (and probably other versions) already made an app.config file for Forms applications.  I've edited the app.config on multiple occasions without creating a new app.config file.  However, I just created a new application and I can't find the app.config file.  I hit Show All files and it still doesn't show.  I know I've seen the answer somewhere before, but I can't remember where.  Sorry for the easy question.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it actually there on disk? There are some other scenarios where VS will create one for you, e.g. adding properties to the settings file.

Comment: That might be what I did before.  I think I added a setting, then deleted it because I wasn't sure I did it right, and then I saw the app.config file.  I'll check in just a minute.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I had tried adding the connection string through the Settings tab, then deleted it, and saw the app.config file there.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create one its not there by default.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer as it is correct, but the way that I got it to show up is the comments to the OP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the app.config file is created automatically, for example if the designer needs to put some information in it, but it's not created by default for all project types when you create a new project.

If it's not there it's because it hasn't been needed yet. It isn't hidden somewhere, so just create it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Does usually depend on your project type, for instance a wcf project or a asp.net mvc project, a config file is usually created for you. If its a basic forms app, just go and add a app.config in.